# 'The transaction has aborted' error after transaction completed

Tags: c#, transactionscope

In the following method, I want to upload and save an image to a server directory, then insert a record (with that image's path as a field value) to database in a transaction scope. but after transaction complete (in next line of `ts.Complete()` - when first transaction scope's using statement complete with `{` ) I take this error:'The transaction has aborted'. how can I resolve it?

This is my method:

```
    private void Save( String fullPath, Uploader DocImageUploader, string docImageFileName, htPinPadDelivery pinPadDelivery, User user, Enumes.ActionType actionType)
    {
        BasketResult<bool> rtnBasketResult = new BasketResult<bool>();
        fullPath += "\\";

        using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions()
        {
            IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
            Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)
        }))
        {
            bool transactionIsSuccess = true;

            if (!Directory.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                String path = Helper.GetFileName(fullPath);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            //Upload image to a server directory:
            transactionIsSuccess = UploadFile(DocImageUploader, fullPath, docImageFileName, user);

            //Insert to database
            if (transactionIsSuccess)
            {
                pinPadDelivery.UploadedDocImage = docImageFileName;

                BasketResult<Boolean> basketResultOfSave = PinPadDeliveriesSave(actionType, pinPadDelivery, user.UserID);
                transactionIsSuccess = basketResultOfSave.IsSuccess;
                if (!transactionIsSuccess)
                    basketResultOfSave.persianErrorMessages.Add(Messages.Err_UploadFileFaild);
            }
            else
                transactionIsSuccess = false;

            using (TransactionScope outOfTransactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)) 
            {
                rtnBasketResult.IsSuccess = transactionIsSuccess;
                rtnBasketResult.Result.Add(transactionIsSuccess);
                if (!transactionIsSuccess)
                    rtnBasketResult.persianErrorMessages.Add(Messages.Err_UploadFileFaild);

                outOfTransactionScope.Complete();
            }

            if (transactionIsSuccess)
                ts.Complete();
        }

    }
```

with deeper review I knew that the main error is:

> Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative tool.

for description : I'm debugging my codes in vs, and connect to other server for getting data from database. database server MSDTC  has set in accordance with [this link](http://www.prairiefyre.com/kb/KnowledgebaseArticle50896.aspx?Keywords=in%20use):

Comment: What about try catch and see the detailed error? Nothing helpful?

Comment: There is no helpful description. exception message is :'The transaction has aborted'